# Ubuntu 18.04 installing nvidia-driver-440 forces me to install nvidia-driver-450

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

As someone killed my nvidia driver on a remote machine recently, I'm trying to reinstall version 440. But whenever I call `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440` the package manager wants to install packages of the version 450.

These are the commands that I run to reinstall my nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
reboot
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440
```

Does anybody know how I can get the packages of driver version 440?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem a while back. To solve this problem, I had to install the correct driver by using the Ubuntu "Additional Drivers" application.

Please ensure that the NVIDIA card is currently being used before opening the application or else the drivers may not show up in the application. This can be checked by using the "NVIDIA X Server" application.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I cannot use these applications, because I'm using an SSH connection.